# Should I have not calculated the unit vector when calculating the direction derivative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

My function is $$f(x,y)=2x+5y^2$$
The point is $$P(1,1)$$
The vector is $$\overrightarrow{u}=(2,1)$$
To calculate the directional derivative I, first, determined that it is, indeed, differentiable in $(1,1)$.

Then, I calculated the gradient, which is $∇f=(f'_x,f'_y)=(2,10y)$

Then, I calculated the unit vector $u'=(\frac 2{\sqrt{5}},\frac 1{\sqrt{5}})$

Then, I calculated $f'v(1,1)=(\frac {14}{\sqrt 5})$

My teacher did the same, but didn't calculate the unit vector, so their result was $14$. Why did they do that? Am I wrong in doing the way I'm doing?

Comment: Of course what you did is correct. You should do dot product with the unit vector to find the magnitude of directional derivative

Comment: Does the problem ask for the value of the directional derivative, or for a corresponding first-order prediction of change along the given vector?

Which of these you need usually depends on the actual application.

Comment: the value @user3716267

Comment: @MathLover so, can I assume my teacher was wrong?

Comment: Your teacher was not wrong. There are two competing definitions of directional derivatives, one of which takes magnitude of the vector into account, while the other doesn't. None of the two are *wrong*, but you do need to be consistent.